# lua ide with syntax sensitive reminder

Tags: iphone, lua, coronasdk

I am using Corona to develop ios app.
I use XCode as IDE.
But I found that XCode does not support Lua syntax sensitive reminder as it does in Objective-c.
Is there an Mac IDE can integrate Corona keyword dictionary and highlight to help and accelerate coding?
And if it can support project files navigation will be better!

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2011/02/22/corona-ide-multiplataform-corona-editor-based-eclipse) might be interesting. Its provided by the community and not very stable, but, its worth a shot. 
[This](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Corona/GettingStarted/Dev) shows a eclipse walkthrough.

Answer (score 1):

[TextAdept](http://code.google.com/p/textadept/) might also be interesting, since it's super-extensible, and already has an LPEG lexer for Lua, which could easily be adjusted for supporting Corona. And everything is scripted in Lua, so no extra language to learn ;)

Comment: Actually I like text adept so much that I am willing to learn lua to customize it :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try [ZeroBrane Studio Lua IDE](http://studio.zerobrane.com/). I've recently added Love2d and Moai auto-complete (there are several [demos on the website](http://studio.zerobrane.com/tutorials.html)) and it should be possible to add Corona API too, but I can't find a good description or documentation for the API calls.

The APIs I've implemented provide not only function names, but also a description, arguments, and return parameters (this is a snippet from one of Moai functions):

```
  addChild = {
    type = "function",
    description = "Attaches a child action for updating.",
    args = '(self: MOAIAction, child: MOAIAction)',
    returns = '(self: MOAIAction)',
  },
```

If there is a description like this for Corona SDK, I should be able to incorporate it into the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The Lua plugin in IntelliJ has support for the Corona API (full disclosure I am the author)

https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/lua-for-idea/wiki/Home